# Random Green Highlighting in Atom?

Tags: atom-editor

I've been using Atom for a few months now. Recently, (after an update, I presume,) it's started showing me something I don't understand despite my best efforts, and it's become quite distracting.

I can't tell what the heck this random green highlighting is trying to tell me.

[image: random green highlighting]

Comment: Very odd. Would you mind listing the Community Packages you have installed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The green highlighting was removed when I  disabled a package called "Refactor", by "hax".

(That could actually be because disabling "Refactor" stopped package "js-refactor" from running, since the latter depends on the former.)